# How to run cucumber scenario multiple time without using Scenario Outline

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

In my cucumber jvm project, I want to execute my scenario 10 times with the same set of data (data being provided in excel) without using scenario outline.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: What behavior are you using this for?

Comment: In my API project, I am sending JSON data as a input. Now my JSON input is remains same except ID field changing continuously (which I am generating using random number). As my rest of Input remaining constant always I just want to repeat this scenario say 10 times.

Comment: So your system is generating the random number? In that case you only need to run it twice, verifying the 2 id's are different. I think you ate over engineering it.

Comment: No, my system is not generating random number. My system needs ID field to be unique each time. Along with ID field there are 200+ fields which I need to send as input request for API which in sends me some response(around 20 fields). In my case I want to send input request and check output whether it is as expected. I need to perform same set of steps for 10 different inputs

Comment: if you are trying to use excel to provide data instead of example table you can try [qaf gherkin client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where you can specify excel file to provide test data `Examples:{'datafile':'resources/testdata.xls'}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all `Scenario Outline` is designed to be used in cases when your input data is changing. So that doesn't fit your case in the first place.

AFAIK you have the following options:

**Set the logic internally in the step**. 
Meaning looping through the required actions inside you step glue code.

```
@Then("^Repetitive step$")
public void repetitive_step(final String repetitions) throws Throwable {

int reps = Integer.valueOf(repetitions);

    for(int i=0; i<reps; i++){
        // your step code
    }    
}
```

**Repeat your step in the feature file itself**. So if that's just a one time occasion that you want to try and do not care about the aesthetics, you can just copy paste the scenario as many times as you need in the feature file.

Comment: Here we are repeating a single step but I want to repeat two steps. Like in 'When' step I will perform some action and in 'Then' step I will verify the result. I want to repeat this set of two steps (When, Then) one after other.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a for loop inside of a Scenario. I've seen this similar problem around a couple of places, but the best you can do for now is simply design your feature so that your preliminary steps are defined in the background and then you have a scenario outline that loops through your section.

If you're available to using a different framework, I've been working on a project called Kherkin that allows you to loop a specific part of your scenario and many other things things that regular Gherkin doesn't allow you to do. Here is an example of how you would loop only a section of your scenrio:
https://bitbucket.org/Muhatashim/zarif-kherkin/src/master/src/test/kotlin/org/bitbucket/muhatashim/kherkin/lang/script/IterationTest.kt

To learn more about Kherkin: https://bitbucket.org/Muhatashim/zarif-kherkin/src/master/